# Browser showing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi Guys please help me I am new on typescript facing error of `Unexpected token ':'` when I define any type of of variable then show me unexpected token error without its not showing error.

```
let num: string = "how are you";
console.log(num);
```

Browser error
[image: browser showing Error on typescript file execution]

Answer (score 2):

Browsers don’t support TypeScript.

You need to convert it to JavaScript first.

The [TypeScript homepage](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#installation) includes instructions for installing a compiler that you can use to do that.

Comment: but its not working i already convert it into javascript by using command and that command generate my javascript file also

Comment: The image you included shows that you are trying to load a ts file and not a js file. If you are compiling to JS then you’re still using the URL to the TS file in the browser.

Comment: Thanks Quenin. problem solve. Allah Give you more success